# Is it possible to create and checkout a new git branch from CakeBuild?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp, cakebuild

My question is two parts question

**1)** I need to create and checkout a new git branch through cake build. In git, this would be exactly like we do

```
git branch Foo
git checkout Foo
```

The `Cake.Git` addin gives information of the current branch name but I doubt it have functionality to branch and checkout.

**2)** The existing `GitCheckout` method throws exception. There is an existing `ReleaseRC` branch of this repo, still it throws exception. What am I missing here?

```
Task("Checkout")
    .Does(() =>
{
    var repositoryPath = "../../.foo";

    Information(GitBranchCurrent(repositoryPath).FriendlyName); //Prints 'master'

    GitCheckout(repositoryPath, "ReleaseRC", new FilePath[] {}); //Throws error.
});
```

[image: Error]

Comment: What's the new branch for?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: I want to perform some changes on the branch (by cake script) and commit it. Then raise a pull request from it to `master`.

Comment: Does the branch `ReleaseRC` exist on the repo?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: Yes. `So Checkout was not happening because I had to run fetch command. After manually doing so branch gets switched and hence no error.` but now my qq is how to do fetch through cake. I think pull should do the trick.

Comment: Git does: *git-pull - Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch*

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: Yeah. how to do it in cake?

Comment: Can you try to make your changes on `master` then use `GitCheckout` and provide all the modified files in `filePaths` and finally commit && push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible through the Cake.Git addin.  There is however an issue for adding this functionality to the Cake.Git addin, which you can find here:

https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake_Git/issues/52

It would be possible to do this work by calling the git executable directly, using the StartProcess alias, and providing the required arguments.

https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common/ProcessAliases/81E648CC

For example:

```
var exitCodeWithArgument = StartProcess("git", new ProcessSettings{ Arguments = "branch foo" });
```

**UPDATE**: As of version 0.18.0 of the Cake.Git addin it should now be possible to use a new GitCreateBranch alias for doing this.

Comment: For future visitors, PR has been merged. `GitCreateBranch` is available here https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake_Git/blob/develop/src/Cake.Git/GitAliases.Branch.cs